# Creating an Android Preferences Screen

Tags: android, fonts, sharedpreferences, typeface

So I followed [this](http://android-elements.blogspot.ie/2011/06/creating-android-preferences-screen.html) tutorial but I'm unsure how I write the last part up to incorporate the different font family, font colours and background colours.

I want to use Courier New, Times New Roman, Monospace, Sans-Serif (DEFAULT) for the font family choices. Black, white, green (#00FF00), and Midnight Blue (#003366) for the font colours.  Finally the background colours will be white, black, pink(#FF00FF), and brown(#663300).

I have the preferences screen showing up fine enough from that tutorial but I'm just not too sure how the last bit of the tutorial works.  If somebody can give me example from the above items I've noted, it would be great help.

Here are the arrays in my strings.xml:

```
 <!-- Prefs Arrays -->
<!-- Background Colours -->
<string-array name="bg_colours">
 <item>White</item>
 <item>Black</item>
 <item>Pink</item>
 <item>Brown</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="bg_values">
 <item>1</item>
 <item>2</item>
 <item>3</item>
 <item>4</item>
</string-array>

<!-- Font Colour -->
<string-array name="font_colours">
 <item>Black</item>
 <item>White</item>
 <item>Green</item>
 <item>Blue</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="font_values">
 <item>1</item>
 <item>2</item>
 <item>3</item>
 <item>4</item>
</string-array>

<!-- Font Family -->
<string-array name="font_family">
 <item>Courier New</item>
 <item>Times New Roman</item>
 <item>Monospace</item>
 <item>Sans-Serif (Default)</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="family_values">
 <item>1</item>
 <item>2</item>
 <item>3</item>
 <item>4</item>
</string-array>
```

Here is the PreferenceCategory in my prefs.xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory
     android:title="@string/prefs_options">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="pref_type1"
            android:title="@string/prefs_bg_colour"
            android:summary="Select background colour"
            android:entries="@array/bg_colours"
            android:entryValues="@array/bg_values"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            />
         <ListPreference
            android:key="pref_type2"
            android:title="@string/prefs_font_colour"
            android:summary="Select font colour"
            android:entries="@array/font_colours"
            android:entryValues="@array/font_values"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            />
          <ListPreference
            android:key="pref_type3"
            android:title="@string/prefs_font_family"
            android:summary="Select font family"
            android:entries="@array/font_family"
            android:entryValues="@array/family_values"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            />



  </PreferenceCategory>
```

EDIT: To show Pref.java file:

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.prefs);
    }  

    // String
    public static String Read(Context context, final String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return pref.getString(key, "");
    }

    public static void Write(Context context, final String key, final String value) {
          SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
          // font_editor = font_pref.edit();
          SharedPreferences.Editor font_editor = settings.edit();
          // font_editor.putString("font_style", font_style);
          // font_editor.putString(key, value);
          font_editor.putString(key, value);
          // font_editor.commit();
          font_editor.commit();        
    }

    // Boolean  
    public static boolean ReadBoolean(Context context, final String key, final boolean defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return settings.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static void WriteBoolean(Context context, final String key, final boolean value) {
          SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
          editor.putBoolean(key, value);
          editor.commit();        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's basically it.

Only that you need an activity.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Then call to show it from your code.

Comment: So what exactly you want to do now? Read they preferences from elsewhere?

Comment: What ever is in the string array I want to assign a value to it so the whole app changes to that colour.  So I have the preference screen showing from the tutorial but I don't have any assigned values such as #FFFFFF for the second item in the font colorrs array.

Comment: Use hex color values in the `bg_values` array instead of just integers. Then read your color preferences using `Read(Context context, final String key)` method and do whatever with that color. Are you asking how to change your application color? Then it's a separate question altogether.